# React Navigation passing parameters to stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have the following code below:

```
const OrderStackComponent = (status: string) => {
  return <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="OrdersScreen" component={Orders} initialParams={{status: status}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="OrdersDetailsScreen" component={OrdersDetailsScreen} initialParams={{status: status}}/>
  </Stack.Navigator>
}

const OrderTopTabs = () => {
  return <TopTabs.Navigator>
  <TopTabs.Screen name="InProgressTab" component={OrderStackComponent} options={{ title: "In Progress" }}/>
    <TopTabs.Screen name="CompletedTab" component={OrderStackComponent} options={{ title: "Completed" }}/>
    <TopTabs.Screen name="CancelledTab" component={OrderStackComponent} options={{ title: "Cancelled" }}/>
  </TopTabs.Navigator>
}
```

`OrderStackComponent` is a function that returns a `Stack.Navigator`. I want to pass a parameter to `OrderStackComponent` so that I can use that function as its `initialParams`, however when I try to use `OrderStackComponent("My Parameter")` it returns an error saying

`Got an invalid value for 'component' prop for the screen 'InProgressTab'. It must be a valid React Component`

The error is pretty understandable, it's just that I AM passing a valid react component. I believe I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using OrderStackComponent("My Parameter") in your TopTabs screen elements, try this:

```
<TopTabs.Screen 
    name="InProgressTab" 
    component={OrderStackComponent}
    initialParams={{ status: "My Parameter"}}
    options={{ title: "In Progress" }}
/>
```